# Concat actually concatenates instead of adds to array. React Native Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-native-listview

Im new to react Native and Javascript programming in general and Im trying to create a simple 'To Do' app with in React Native and redux.

Im attempting to add a 'To Do' to the the array in my reducer as seen below.

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes'

const initialState = {
    data: []
};

export default function toDo(state = initialState, action) {

    let list
    console.log(action + " action")
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD:
        list = state.data.concat([action.toDoData])
            return {
                ...state,
                data: list || []
            }
        default:
             return state;
    }
}
```

The result shows
[AddToDo Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMaVx.png)
you can see 'First Thing' and 'Second Thing' are my two added results and they concat onto the same row.

My first thought was that there was something wrong with my dumb or presentational ListView which takes it data as below.

```
<MyList data={this.props.data}/>
```

So i tried this...

```
<MyList data={['firstThing', 'secondThing', 'thirdThing']}/>
```

and it [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4p6L.png)!!! This is the reason I'm thinking the error is in the reducer.

Please let me know what other code would be useful. Any insights would be MUCH appreciated.

This is the action.

```
import * as types from './actionTypes.js';

export function addToList(toDoData) {
    return {
        type: types.ADD,
        toDoData: toDoData
    };
}
```

Comment: Just FYI you should always use semicolons. There can be some pretty ugly bugs.

Comment: Your code looks right, just fix console.log and add more of them to find the problem. They should look like this: `console.log('action', action);` (comma instead of plus sign)

Comment: Not really related to your answer, but I'd use Immutable in your reducers. You don't have to of course, but I've come across some nasty bugs regarding object references without it. Immutable-types' methods would also greatly help in manipulating your data structures!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some insights on how you actually 'push' data into an array

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.push("Kiwi");

//fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Kiwi"];
```

Or you can just

```
export default function toDo(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD:
      return {
        data: [...state.data, action.toDoData]
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Immutable Javascript i think is the goal though no?

Comment: you can still use the spread operator and push the array at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the array spread operator, i.e.

```
export default function toDo(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD:
      return {
        data: [...state.data, action.toDoData]
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is your action.toDoData an array? If yes, then it should be

> state.data.concat(action.toDoData)

Comment: Nope its just the string input. Iv edited the question with the action.

Answer (score 0):

I think that somehow, into your first loop you added string into state.data...
Try something like this:
`list = state.data.concat(action.toDoData)`
Or with ES6 spread:
`list = [...state.data, action.toDodata]`